# How do I use the tabs API?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-import

I am creating a program that needs to interact with other tabs on the window that the HTML file is opened on, and I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) code. However, I think that I have implemented it incorrectly as it does nothing. Here is my (incomplete) code:

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Workench</title>

    <script src="dependencies/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dependencies/index.css">

</head>

<body>

    <nav id="toolbar">

        <div id="file">

            <label>File</label>

            <br>

            <button onclick="toolbar.file.saveDoc()">Save</button>
            <button onclick="toolbar.file.newDoc()">New</button>
            <button onclick="toolbar.file.loadDoc()">Load</button>

        </div>

        <div id="upload">

            <label>Upload</label>

            <br>

            <button onclick="toolbar.upload.seasaw()">Seasaw</button>
            <button onclick="toolbar.upload.googleClassroom()">Google Classroom</button>

        </div>

    </nav>

</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
import "browser";

const toolbar = {

    file : {

        saveDoc () {

            browser.tabs.create({url: "docs.google.com"}).then(() => {
                browser.tabs.executeScript({
                  code: "console.log('hello');"
                });
              });

        },

        newDoc () {

            

        },

        loadDoc() {

            

        }

    }

};
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

For context, this is for my school. It needs to essentially be a text editor that then automatically uploads the text to the platforms that my school uses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that docs.google.com has not provided you permission for this, see the page you have shared

[image]

You will need to make sure you have [host permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#host_permissions) for the URLs you intend to interact with.

I advise you to first try this with pages of the same domain opened in a new tab and when that works, you may venture into the usage with different domains.

Comment: Thanks but how do I go about changing the permissions?

Comment: @DarcySutton you will need to apply permission changes in a different manner in the different browsers. Example: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Comment: Is there a way I can get the browser to ask permission from the tab (like when the tab tries to access your location)?

Comment: @DarcySutton I'm not aware of such a feature, unfortunately.